# find an algorithm to find MST in linear time while each edge has the same weight

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, trees

I have been disscussing this problem with a lot of my friends . However no solution has been found. 
let G= w is a weight function 
for each e in E w(e)=1
find MST of G in O(|V|+|E|)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every edge has weight $1$, then every spanning tree of $G$ has the same weight: $\lvert V\rvert-1$.  So, all that you actually have to do here is find any $O(\lvert V\rvert+\lvert E\rvert)$-time algorithm for finding ANY spanning tree for $G$.

For instance: breadth-first search can be used to do this, with worst-case performance $O(\lvert V\rvert+\lvert E\rvert)$.